# How to set runtimeExecutable for node in launch.json config for VScode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging

I want to set runtimeExecutable variable so that it works for anyone who clones the git and have the node debugger ready out of the box,

How do I set up the config so that runtimeExecutable selects automatically the default nvm set on the machine ?

I tried setting the ${env:HOME} but it's not enough since people are using different node versions with diffrent paths